# How do I not call a function?

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I think it's obvious that I just won't call it, but I am trying to create an exception if it returns "None". I have my code here:

```
    if self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]:
        self.logger.info("******* RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION VALIDATION ENABLED ******* ")
        db_total_table_unique_count_dict={}
        s3_total_table_unique_count_dict={}
        db_total_table_unique_count_dict=self.getDBUniqueValueCounts(db_total_table_unique_count_dict)
        s3_total_table_unique_count_dict=self.getS3UniqueValueCounts(s3_total_table_unique_count_dict)
        ret_unique_counts=SourceValidation.findDiff(db_total_table_unique_count_dict,s3_total_table_unique_count_dict,"UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON")
        ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']=db_total_table_unique_count_dict
        ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts']=s3_total_table_unique_count_dict
        data_validation={}
        data_validation.update({"VALIDATION_TYPE":"UNIQUE_COUNT"})
        data_validation.update({"DATABASE":db_name})
        data_validation.update({"RUN_TIMESTAMP":self.run_time_stamp})

        if ret_unique_counts is not None:

            if ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].get(self.table)["RESULT"]==False:
                data_validation.update({"TABLES": {list(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].keys())[0]:{"NON_BATCH_VALIDATION":{"FAILED":not bool(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"][self.table]["RESULT"]),"FAILURE_MSG":"counts do not match DB UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']) +" S3 UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts'])}}}})
            else:
                data_validation.update({"TABLES": {list(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].keys())[0]:{"NON_BATCH_VALIDATION":{"FAILED":not ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"][self.table]["RESULT"],"FAILURE_MSG":"counts  match DB UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']) +" S3 UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts'])}}}})
                self.writeReportsToS3("UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON",data_validation,"datavalidation/reporting/"+"UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"+"/"+key)

    else:
        self.logger.info("******* UNIQUE COUNT VALIDATION IS DISABLED ******* ")
```

The error I am getting is:

```
    if ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].get(self.table)["RESULT"]==False:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

So I basically want to not call the function "findDiff" if it returns "None". I'm not sure how to do that, so I thought I can continue my "if" statement if it returns "None" anyway, to skip over it by writing `if ret_unique_counts is not None:`. I tried that and it still throws the same error. I'm not sure what else to do. I don't want to take out "findDiff" because I have a list of tables it iterates through, but if one isn't there I want it to skip over it.

UPDATE--------------------------------------

I updated my code like this:

```
    if self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]:
        self.logger.info("******* RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION VALIDATION ENABLED ******* ")
        db_total_table_unique_count_dict={}
        s3_total_table_unique_count_dict={}
        db_total_table_unique_count_dict=self.getDBUniqueValueCounts(db_total_table_unique_count_dict)
        s3_total_table_unique_count_dict=self.getS3UniqueValueCounts(s3_total_table_unique_count_dict)
        ret_unique_counts=SourceValidation.findDiff(db_total_table_unique_count_dict,s3_total_table_unique_count_dict,"UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON")
        ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']=db_total_table_unique_count_dict
        ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts']=s3_total_table_unique_count_dict
        data_validation={}
        data_validation.update({"VALIDATION_TYPE":"UNIQUE_COUNT"})
        data_validation.update({"DATABASE":db_name})
        data_validation.update({"RUN_TIMESTAMP":self.run_time_stamp})
        if not ret_unique_counts:
            if ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].get(self.table)["RESULT"]==False:
                    data_validation.update({"TABLES": {list(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].keys())[0]:{"NON_BATCH_VALIDATION":{"FAILED":not bool(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"][self.table]["RESULT"]),"FAILURE_MSG":"counts do not match DB UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']) +" S3 UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts'])}}}})
            else:
                data_validation.update({"TABLES": {list(ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"].keys())[0]:{"NON_BATCH_VALIDATION":{"FAILED":not ret_unique_counts["UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"][self.table]["RESULT"],"FAILURE_MSG":"counts  match DB UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['db_unique_counts']) +" S3 UNIQUE COUNT: "+str(ret_unique_counts['s3_unique_counts'])}}}})
            self.writeReportsToS3("UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON",data_validation,"datavalidation/reporting/"+"UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON"+"/"+key)

        else:
            self.logger.info("******* UNIQUE COUNT VALIDATION IS DISABLED ******* ")
```

I just added `if not ret_unique_counts` in the "if" statement. It runs through each table listed in the dictionary, it skips over the table that's not listed like I want, but there is no file that is written to S3 even though the code runs all the way through without errors. I'm not sure where the issue is now, but I think I'm getting close.

Comment: That line has two places where it does a subscript.  Either `ret_unique_counts` is None, or the result of `.get(self.table)` is None.

Comment: i think it's the result of .get(self.table) because that's the line it's erroring out on

Comment: when i print(ret_unique_counts) it returns this: {'UNIQUE_COUNT_COMPARISON': {}}
so maybe that's the issue? im not sure how to check .get(self.table)

Comment: That's an empty subdictionary, so any possible `.get()` call will return none.

Comment: ah that makes sense after i just realized it. so if .get() returns None, how do I ignore that and move onto the next table that's in the dictionary?

Comment: so when i replace .get(self.table) with [self.table] it return an KeyError: TABLE3. So it throws a keyerror showing the table that's not in the dictionary. i just want to ignore that and only apply this to what's in the dictionary